# Name of anime/cartoon show where a flying robot uses parts of itself in flying patterns (alphabet letters) to upgrade itself to defeat enemies

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon, mecha

I recall a show where a sole pilot would fly a fighter/mech(a) through various patterns under the directions of a base/station commander. I can't remember the English name for it, and don't have any idea what other names it might have gone under. Sorry.

The pair have a semblance of the old Robotech/Macross boss/hero feel about them. The base commander looked a lot like the original Robotech captain (Henry J. Gloval) if memory serves, even down to the 'acting' and mannerisms.

As to the patterns, they would resemble or actually be letters of the alphabet, the fighter/mech(a) would split up into parts (top/bottom or sides, etc) and then recombine at different angles/speed to, in effect, upgrade itself and gain new abilities to battle new enemies.

Examples would be letters like V, P, T, N and others, where parts of the fighter/mech(a) would start at the ends of the letter, like V, and meet in the middle, or the T-manoeuvrer I remember fondly, as the pilot couldn't complete it because the power require to re-join the parts and force-fly down the straight part of the imaginary T was too great. It had to be done while battling a boss and using the explosive energy of the enemies' guns/bombs to help in completing the manoeuvrer.

It was on TV, yes good old analogue TV, some time in the mid 80s-90s, although might have been made earlier as it came from overseas.

I have googled and googled, but this specific one seems to be buried real deep and as I can't even remember the name of the series, actors, or parts of it I'm stuck. Which is why I ended up here.

And yes, I have trawled through the questions and tags here as well to try and find something similar. No luck.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the tags @fez!

Comment: Choudenji Machine Voltes V has a concept like that, but I can't find pictures of the transformations to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for looking @Ocean. The story I recall has a sole/solo protagonist, and is not part of any team when piloting the mech. There was a base commander and a scientist who helped out, not sure about other characters. The enemy mechs might have had a pilot as well, or were autonomously controlled (AI?) by the 'bad' guys.

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Lightspeed Electroid Albegas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightspeed_Electroid_Albegas), although the alphabet combinations were less complicated and based on the Greek alphabet. There were plans at one time to adapt it into a third series of Voltron, but they didn't come to frution.

Comment: [Getter Robo G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getter_Robo_G) as well.